# "Firebase cannot be loading because running scripts is disabled on this system", VSCode on Windows

Tags: windows, firebase, powershell, visual-studio-code, firebase-cli

I have installed the firebase tools, however whenever I try to initialize it in my rootfolder, using the terminal from Vscode, I receive the following error. Why is that?

[image]

Comment: Please check this thread: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1627

Comment: Run the commands from simple CMD, worked for me...

Comment: Bypassing the execution policy in PowerShell may be dangerous. I recommend to rename the file (to firebase_old.ps1 for example) or to delete it.
It is much safer.

Answer (score 83):

### TLDR: Just delete your `firebase.ps1` file and try again

I would **not** recommend bypassing the execution policy on PowerShell, as it makes your system more vulnerable to malicious scripts.

Instead, simply delete the `firebase.ps1` file at the location indicated by the error message and try running the command again.

Note: in case the above doesn't work, you might need to clear your npm cache by running `npm cache clean --force`.

Comment: Solved my problem!

Comment: Solved my problem too...

Comment: Thanks, @Fappaz, this is a neat and terrific solution! It worked for me as well. It's really not an efficient approach to allow malicious scripts.

Comment: deleting the file solved my problem too! I use the windows 'run' app to acces the file location

Comment: that should be the answer

Comment: this should be marked as the answer

Comment: If I already ran the ExecutionPolicy Bypass command before seeing this answer, how do I undo that?

Comment: @ChristiaanAdams if you ran with scope `Process`, you can simply close PowerShell as it won't persist. Otherwise, if you ran with some other scope (e.g.: `LocalMachine`), then you should roll it back by executing `Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope LocalMachine -ExecutionPolicy Undefined`

Comment: Excellent, thank you @Fappaz

Answer (score 82):

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass
```

Install firebase globally

```bash
npm i -g firebase
```

and then,

```bash
firebase login
firebase init
```

Comment: It works fine...but every time I want to use firebase I had to run this command first...is there any permanent set of execution policy?

Comment: It looks like to be a per context command. The error goes away after the policy is enabled first on each run, as @ShrishSharma sad.

Comment: In my case I wanted a run configuration in IntelliJ IDEA to start the Firebase emulator, but I didn't want a global permanent change to the PowerShell policy for security reasons. The trick is to create a run configuration, of type "Shell Script", Execute Type = Script text, and on the Script Text command include both commands separated by semi-colon. E.g.: Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass; firebase emulators:start --only "auth,firestore,functions"

Answer (score 15):

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54776674/1536286

Run the following at the terminal in VS Code (make sure the app is run with the option **Running as Administrator** as suggested by @MaylorTaylor)

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

Then run the script in that same console.

Comment: Hello, no that did not work but I did run the script on the directory from cmd

Comment: You need to run this command in VS Code / Powershell / CMD while the app is "Running as Administrator"

Answer (score 9):

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 6):

Open Windows Power Shell as Administrator and then run the below command to change Execution Policy setting to RemoteSigned

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

Now change directory to your project folder and run the following

```
firebase login
firebase init
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, here are the exact steps:

In VSCode, select `Terminal > New Terminal`.
Next, type `cmd`. This will switch you from PowerShell to a regular command prompt.

```
PS C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\FirebaseMessaging\cloud-functions> cmd
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1848]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\FirebaseMessaging\cloud-functions>firebase login
i  Firebase optionally collects CLI and Emulator Suite usage and error reporting information to help improve our products. Data is collected in accordance with Google's privacy policy (https://policies.google.com/privacy) and is not used to identify you.

? Allow Firebase to collect CLI and Emulator Suite usage and error reporting information? No
```

Next, your browser should open - follow the Authorization steps. Then:

```
Waiting for authentication...

+  Success! Logged in as user@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Close cmd and powershell and VS Code.
Then right click on VS code---RunAs Administrator
and in the VS Code Terminal run the following command:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

Then in the same VS Code cmd run:

```
firebase login
firebase init
```

This should solve your problem.
Windows now comes with an extra layer of security to protect your  OS environment from random scripts running in the background without admin privilege's.
Most Random Scripts(From browser engines on unverified sites and applications) are also bad for your OS,unless you are running them yourself as an admin or as a developer,provided you know what you are doing.
Firebase scripts are pretty safe.

Answer (score 1):

`Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass`

Run this in your current working directory, i.e where Firebase is initialized and run this command, worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Simply in VScode switch from PowerShell to cmd
and type this command.

```
firebase login
```

And you will be redirected to your browser to allow Firebase CLI to access the account connected to your firebase project and then type this command.

```
firebase init
```

That should work

Comment: This worked for me, I am using Android Studio and facing the same issue and when i switched to cmd terminal and it is working now. Thanks @Ahmed Abd El-Moez

Answer (score 1):

If using VScode, installing the PowerShell extension by Microsoft will solve this issue.

[enter link description here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell)

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me: is that i am using Windows 11 and i used to use **Windows Power Shell** instead of **Command Prompt**

[image]

In case want to use **Windows Power Shell** you have to run this cmd first:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting Execution Policy. I ran windows terminal as administrator instead of VS code terminal and execute command without an issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**In cmd it works**

firebase login

firebase init

Select project

Answer (score 0):

When you encountered the issue with the Firebase CLI in PowerShell, you were advised to run

> Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

as an administrator. By executing this command, you would be granting permission to run locally created scripts and would be able to execute the Firebase CLI or other scripts on your system.

It's important to note that changing the execution policy can have security implications. By allowing script execution, you might be exposed to potentially harmful or malicious scripts. Therefore, it's recommended to exercise caution and only change the execution policy if you trust the scripts you intend to run.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running powershell as Admin, run it normally and use the following:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```

It is more secured than other answers.