# "Firebase running scripts is disabled on this system"

Tags: node.js, firebase, visual-studio-code, npm, deployment

I have installed the firebase tools, however whenever I try to initialize it in my rootfolder, using the terminal from Vscode, I receive the following error.

**firebase : File C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\fi
running scripts is disabled on this system. For more
about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/**

Why is that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Firebase cannot be loading because running scripts is disabled on this system", VSCode on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60594178/firebase-cannot-be-loading-because-running-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer to your question, Hope will help you, Thanks.

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60594178/firebase-cannot-be-loading-because-running-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system)

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. If it is a duplicate question, [vote to close](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) as such and/or leave a comment once you [earn](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472) enough [reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). If not, *tailor the answer to this specific question*.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the firebase script where npm is located.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).