# Activating virtual environment for django in command line versus activating it in the Atom terminal

Tags: python, django, command-line, virtualenv, atom-editor

I am having a hard time activating virtual environment, after I have created it.
The thing is, that when I try to activate virtual environment in command line, it works -

`virtualenvironmentname\Scripts\activate`

But when I try to run the same command in Atom, (I am using the Terminus package in order to be able to run the terminal inside Atom) I get this message -
File (path\activate.ps1) cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies
at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.

I was trying to run it by using slightly different commands such as -
`activate virtualenvironmentname` or `activate (virtualenvironmentname)`
, but it did not work.

I was further investigating a little more and I have found some clues, that I might need to change some script execution policies, but I am little bit afraid to do so, because I do not want to mess up my computer since I am just a beginner when it comes to system configuration.

Could anybody please tell me, how could I fix this problem? It would be really convenient for me to be able to run the virtual environment from Atom, since I will be writing my Python and Django lines of code there.

Thank You very much and I hope, that my description of the problem was somehow understandable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54776324/powershell-bug-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system

Comment: I have realized, that I can probably use both Atom and command line (when necessary), because it is kind of possible. So consider this post to be solved. (but You can still try to solve the problem :D)