# "ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system" in Developer Powershell for VS 2019

Tags: powershell, visual-studio

I'm trying to run a .ps1 file from Developer Powershell for VS 2019 and this is what I get:

```
PS C:\Users\name\Documents\GitHub\proj> ./test.ps1
./test.ps1 : File C:\Users\name\Documents\GitHub\proj\test.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ ./test.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

I've followed the steps at https://stackoverflow.com/a/68381260 and I can run a .ps1 file in normal PowerShell, just not in Developer Powershell for VS 2019. Is there some trick to this, or it blocked for a reason? This is the output of `Get-ExecutionPolicy -List` from Developer Powershell for VS 2019:

```
PS C:\Users\name\Documents\GitHub\proj> Get-ExecutionPolicy -List

        Scope ExecutionPolicy
        ----- ---------------
MachinePolicy       Undefined
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process       Undefined
  CurrentUser       Undefined
 LocalMachine       Undefined
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PowerShell says "execution of scripts is disabled on this system."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/powershell-says-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system)

Comment: @KenWhite no - my issue is in Developer Powershell for VS 2019 specifically.

Comment: Did you execute `Set-ExecutionPolicy` in your developer PowerShell or in your regular PowerShell?

Comment: Developer PowerShell is still PowerShell, and policy execution permissions are set exactly the same way in both, which means that the link I provided does in fact apply.

Comment: @stackprotector

Comment: Did you open a new PowerShell after executing `Set-ExecutionPolicy`? Also what are your parameters for `Set-ExecutionPolicy`?

Comment: Did you set the execution policy for another user by accident? Are there group or local policies that (re-)set the execution policy?

Comment: If you do not want to mess with execution policies, just execute `powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File ./test.ps1` instead of `./test.ps1`.